# Cancel the one time scheduled work in Android

Tags: android, service, android-workmanager

I have a below use case to implement.

The user schedules a one-time work of downloading some files after 15 min with WiFi as the constraint. The user loses the Wifi before the scheduled work can get started.
Now the requirement is if the file has not been downloaded yet (30 min after the scheduled time). Cancel the work itself.

Should I create one more work to check the status of the downloading work and act accordingly?

Comment: For this scenario, you should use the WorkManager and schedule your task with single request and rest all the things will be taken care by WorkManager.

Comment: How will the work get canceled 30 min after the scheduled time if the file is not downloaded yet? 
I think the work will be in a db and as soon as constraints(WiFI availability) are met, It will get executed.

Comment: You can start a timer of 30 mins if you want otherwise let that file get downloaded